# thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' has overflowed its stack

Tags: polkadot

May I ask what is the issue with starting the corresponding relay chain reporting an error.
Check that the disk and memory are sufficient.

```
dell@dell:~/Test/Relay$ ./polkadot \
> --validator \
> --name RelayNode \
> --base-path /home/dell/Test/Relay/store/node \
> --chain /home/dell/Test/Relay/relay.json \
> --port 20335 --ws-port 9946 --rpc-port 9935  \
> --out-peers 1000  --in-peers 1000 \
> --rpc-methods=unsafe \
> --rpc-cors=all \
> --allow-private-ipv4 --rpc-external --ws-external
2023-05-15 06:20:03 It isn't safe to expose RPC publicly without a proxy server that filters available set of RPC methods.
2023-05-15 06:20:03 It isn't safe to expose RPC publicly without a proxy server that filters available set of RPC methods.
2023-05-15 06:20:03 Parity Polkadot
2023-05-15 06:20:03 ✌️  version 0.9.12-unknown-x86_64-linux-gnu
2023-05-15 06:20:03 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2023
2023-05-15 06:20:03  Chain specification: Rococo Test Testnet
2023-05-15 06:20:03  Node name: RelayNode
2023-05-15 06:20:03  Role: AUTHORITY
2023-05-15 06:20:03  Database: RocksDb at /home/dell/Test/Relay/store/node/chains/rococo_test_testnet/db/full
2023-05-15 06:20:03 ⛓  Native runtime: rococo-300 (parity-rococo-v1.8-0.tx0.au0)
2023-05-15 06:20:03  Local node identity is: 12D3KooWQVQm5hKkb9mUtRb4tUzaF4u2omxajc............
2023-05-15 06:20:03  Highest known block at #2686275
2023-05-15 06:20:03 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
2023-05-15 06:20:03 Listening for new connections on 0.0.0.0:9946.
2023-05-15 06:20:03  Starting BABE Authorship worker

thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
Aborted (core dumped)
```

/home/dell/Test/Relay/store/node/chains/rococo_test_testnet/db/full

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version are you trying to run? the last from the repository?

Comment: I'm also facing the same error while executing a node, rest of 2 nodes are working fine. Seeking for Solution of this.

Comment: I am encountering this issue. Any ideas ?